# Machine learning-based drug design: how to determine the desired properties given a target?

Tags: cheminformatics, drugs, machine-learning

I am working on a machine learning-based drug design project. The machine learning part was easily understood for me being from a computer science background. However, the biochemistry part is what I have troubles understanding.
In machine learning-based drug design such as "https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aap7885", a generator model is trained to output valid molecules (in smiles string), and then, this generator is biased/fine-tuned to output only the molecules with certain chemical properties.

My questions are:

- how do we determine these desired chemical properties? For example, if I want to train my generator model to output molecules that can serve as drugs for Covid-19 disease, what should the chemical properties be, by chemical properties I mostly refer to (logP, hydrogen bond donors, hydrogen bond acceptors, polar surface area, molecular weight, etc.)?
- is there a standard/well-established approach to determine these desired properties given a certain target (in this case, the target is the Sars-Cov-2)?

Comment: I guess some heavy quantum chemistry computations must be involved, like the one prof. Zahradník of the "Prague school" of quantum chemistry developed.

Comment: The answer is *you cannot*, unless you have a large team of pharmacological chemistry geniusses. Firstly you have to define what kind of drug you want. Research the way they work. Find a suitable target region at the virus, or at the human body. And THEN you can try to do whatever machine-learning magic you think you're capable of. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws

Comment: Oh, and the list of chemical properties you show is not even nearly sufficient. The spatial arrangement of anything on the drug that can interact is the key.